# Can I change default production branch and/or integration branch?

Tags: gitlab-ci, to-be-continuous

[to be continuous](https://gitlab.com/groups/to-be-continuous) is a set of advanced ready-to use templates for GitLab CI.

By default, every *to be continuous* template is considering `master` as the default production branch, and `develop` the default integration branch.

Can this default behavior be changed ? For instance, use `main` instead of `master` as the production branch ?

Comment: Description changed. Does it sound clearer to you ? (anyway it's maybe tough to understand as long as you don't know [to be continuous](https://gitlab.com/Orange-OpenSource/tbc))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

Production and integration branches are variabilized using regular expressions:

```yaml
variables:
  # default production ref name (pattern)
  PROD_REF: '/^master$/'
  # default integration ref name (pattern)
  INTEG_REF: '/^develop$/'
```

Simply overriding them shall change the behavior.

Example in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
variables:
  # my production branch
  PROD_REF: '/^main$/'
```

You could even decide that every branch with format `prod-xxx` should be considered as production.
Using a regex here helps:

```yaml
variables:
  # my production branch(es)
  PROD_REF: '/^prod-.*$/'
```

/!\ `$PROD_REF` and `$INTEG_REF` are used to implement pattern matching in GitLab CI rules, so [beware of this GitLab bug](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35438).

If you have a close look at the issue, the conclusion is that only 3 regex patterns are working:

```
pattern1: '/^abcde$/'
pattern5: '/^abcde.*/'
pattern6: '/^abcde/'
```

So make sure you're using one of those.